# migrate db from timezone TLT to IST

Tags: php, date, timezone

My server Timezone is TLT. Now I have to change it to IST.
I have 10000 records in my db where the date[data type:integer] entered was related to the TLT timezone.
When I change the timezone in my server to IST. The date entered 30 Jun as TLT was showing 29 Jun.
 How to make it show correctly?
Whether I have to minus the time difference for all the records?

Comment: By TLT, I assume you mean "East Timor Time" (`"Asia/Dili"`) - but which IST are you referring to?  There are [three different possibilities](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/).

Comment: You should also show some code and describe how you are doing things today.  There's not enough information in your question to know how to help you.

Comment: From Asia/Dili, I have to change it to Asia/Kolkata. I have written a script where i am updating all the records. In table, I have a column time_submitted where i am subtracting 3.30 hrs(to convert it to IST from TLT) since Asia/Dili is 3.30 hrs ahead of Asia/kolkata

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mysql function [CONVERT_TZ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) and update values.

Something like this:

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name` = CONVERT_TZ(`column_name`, 'EST', 'UTC' );
```

Comment: Date was enterted in integer format [strtotime]. I am using postgres